# Django ascii displaying error

Tags: django, view, asciiencoding

Ascii decoding error

Text = `"Hanuman (Sanskrit: हनुमान्, Hanumān), a Hindu deity who was an ardent devotee of Rama according to Hindus legends, and a central character in the Indian epic Ramayana."`

I saved the text into MYSQL table to novarchar column, it inserts successfully.

when i retrieve this data in console, it is displaying correctly. But when i tried to retrieve it via django and display it in template ,it is showing as some ascii characters.

Displaying as `"Hanuman (Sanskrit: à¤¹à¤¨à¥à¤&reg;à¤¾à¤¨à¥, HanumÄn), is a Hindu deity who is an ardent devotee of Rama, a central character in the Indian epic Ramayana."`

Comment: Please show some code. What does the model look like? How are you getting the data? How are you displaying it in the template? How did you insert it in the first place?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/
Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you miss the content type meta tag in your template:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: I had kept that tag also.I fixed it by decoding to utf-8